# java.lang.NullPointerException on extends Activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes. 1st class is my custom toast class and 2nd class is Activity where is onCreate void and button click event.

*I think problem is someone about extends Activity*

THX

**1st Class:**

```
    class MakeToast extends Activity {

    public void makeToast(String string, Boolean type){

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        int TypeLayout;

        if(type == false){
            TypeLayout = R.layout.toast_layout_error;
        }
        else{
            TypeLayout = R.layout.toast_layout_success;
        }

        View layout = inflater.inflate(TypeLayout,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(string);

        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

**2nd Class**

When I click on button apk crash

```
public class Gobygo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ImageButton button_search = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_search);

    button_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MakeToast toast_object = new MakeToast();
            toast_object.makeToast("Alert  !!!!", false);

        }
    });
}
```

}

**HERE IS FULL LOG**

```
08-19 10:17:30.333  26797-26797/com.example.tomastrusik.gobygo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tomastrusik.gobygo, PID: 26797
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.getLayoutInflater(Activity.java:3338)
        at com.example.tomastrusik.gobygo.Gobygo$MakeToast.makeToast(Gobygo.java:87)
        at com.example.tomastrusik.gobygo.Gobygo$2.onClick(Gobygo.java:72)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please post the logcat including a *full* stack trace.

Comment: Even without the Stacktrace it's obvious that you should extend `Toast`instead of `Activity`

Comment: You'd better explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Where is you onCreateView()?

Comment: I want my custom toast class in own class and using this toast class in other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extend `Activity`. In fact, you don't need to extend anything. You are essentially making a static utility function to show a specialized `Toast`.

```
public class ToastUtils {

    private ToastUtils() { /*nobody needs to instantiate this ever*/ }

    public static void makeToast(Context context, boolean success, String text) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        int layoutRes = success ? R.layout.toast_layout_success : R.layout.toast_layout_error;

        View layout = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(text);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Invoke this method by calling `ToastUtils.makeToast(...)` and give it the LayoutInflater from the activity.

Comment: You should pass the context to the method instead of the LayoutInflater since `getApplicationContext()` won’t work in your class.

Comment: Remove the first line from the makeToast method. Causes compile errors. Inflater already exists, plus ToastUtils does not contain a definition for getLayoutInflater nor a definition for getApplicationContext (unless it's an inner class, but that's bad practice, as it's a utility class)